# VScode Latex: Disable syntax highlighting for a range of lines

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, syntax-highlighting, highlight, listings

My VScode with the theme should perform like the following pic:[Good highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND2TR.png)

However, after I add some configurations for `listings`, it becomes:[Bad highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3hWQ.png).

I think the point is the line I circled. There is a `$` who ruins the whole theme. Is there a way to disable the highlight only for this line? Or is there another way to define this Julia code block without this issue?

Comment: it's not clear to me whether the `%` are present in the actual "good highlight", or are only there to grey everything out to emulate a desired highlighting for what follow them, and why you would actually want everything greyed out- it doesn't match the rest of the backslashed things.

Comment: most likely this is a textmate grammar issue. are you using any latex extensions? does this issue reproduce when you disable all extensions and reload?

Comment: @starball Thank you for pointing out the unclear example I gave. The bad highlight means that after I commented out all the configurations given by `\lstdefinelanguage{Julia}`  all the below codes are highlighted with the correct format, rather than with that red and orange.

Comment: I do not get the "extensions" you meant, but this problem does not affect the compiling (just affects beauty ^^).

Comment: find the **TextMate Scope** of the parts that are colored incorrect and correct in both cases and find out why TextMate goes wrong and file a bug report or fix at the language extension

Comment: @rioV8 Thank you for the suggestion. I will check how to do that!

Comment: are you using any VS Code extensions that add additional latex support? also, please add markup that can be used as a [mre] in your question post.